# Is there a way to make a checkbox list in flutter where the user can edit the label of that checkbox? For example a task that needs to be completed

Tags: ios, listview, flutter, checkbox, dart

I am trying to make a UI for an app that lets the user list tasks and check them off as they get them done. But I want the user to be able to seamlessly edit the names of those tasks and then hit a checkbox for completion.

I have tried using a ListView.Builder from this tutorial

https://miro.medium.com/max/186/1*gE4Qj0fFgLFGlSUiy-rn2w.gif
(you might have to copy and paste the Link)

It's just I want to be able to have a checklist show up

Reference:https://medium.com/@DakshHub/flutter-displaying-dynamic-contents-using-listview-builder-f2cedb1a19fb

```
class DyanmicList extends State<ListDisplay> {
List<String> litems = [];
final TextEditingController eCtrl = new TextEditingController();
@override
Widget build (BuildContext ctxt) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Dynamic Demo"),),
  body: new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      new TextField(
        controller: eCtrl,
        onSubmitted: (text) {
          litems.add(text);
          eCtrl.clear();
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      new Expanded(
        child: new ListView.builder
          (
            itemCount: litems.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
              return new Text(litems[Index]);
            }
        )
    )
    ],
  )
  );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to return a `ListTile` in your instead of `Text` inside your `itemBuilder`. The `ListTile` will have a `CheckBox` as a `leading` (takes a widget that will appear on the left side), `Text` as a `title`, and at last, an `IconButton` as a `trailing` (takes a widget that will appear on the right side). When cliked an `AlertDialog` that has a `TextField` appears to edit the text editing the text (`title`).

```
List<String> listItems = [];
  List<bool> listCheck = [];
  final TextEditingController eCtrl = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _textFieldController =
      new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Dynamic Demo"),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new TextField(
            controller: eCtrl,
            onSubmitted: (text) {
              setState(() {
                listItems.insert(0, text);
                listCheck.add(false);
                eCtrl.clear();
              });
            },
          ),
          new Expanded(
            child: new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: listItems.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return new ListTile(
                  leading: Checkbox(
                    value: listCheck[index],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        listCheck[index] = !listCheck[index];
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  title: Text(listItems[index]),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                    onPressed: () {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: Text('TextField in Dialog'),
                            content: TextField(
                              controller: _textFieldController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "${listItems[index]}"),
                            ),
                            actions: <Widget>[
                              new FlatButton(
                                child: new Text('Done'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    listItems[index] =
                                        _textFieldController.text;
                                    _textFieldController.clear();
                                  });
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

You only have to add the `CheckBox` functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `DataTable` widget. It is easy to use and can have editable rows. Adding check list to them is easy as well. You can sort them too. Refer to this tutorial. Do as the tutorial say and you will have a list with checking and deleting ability. But to be able to edit the rows, you need to add this line of code to your DataCells in DataRow: 
`showEditIcon: true,`. I think the tutorial is great with great explanation. But if you need more help, I'll be glad to help.

[CoderzHeaven](https://www.coderzheaven.com/2019/01/24/flutter-tutorials-datatable-android-ios/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply I will try DataTable widget right now, but I don't see the link for the tutorial you mentioned